# MySQL selecting all records and for each select separate record - in one query

Tags: php, mysql, join

I believe what I am trying to achieve here is a **nested** query - however I am unsure how to continue.

I have 2 tables **users** and **notifications** what I am doing is querying **notifications** table to get the details, however I am also *LEFT OUTER JOIN* on users table to get my user information. What I have is like this :

```
          USERS TABLE     
| user id | username | user image |


    NOTIFICATIONS TABLE  
| receiver id | sender id |
```

Just getting the *receivers* information is not an issue as I user the following query :

```
SELECT
    notifications.senderID, notifications.receiverID, users.username, users.image
FROM
    notifications
    LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON users.id = notifications.receiverID
WHERE notifications.receiverID = ' xxx '
```

**What I need to add** is a way to foreach record found also grab the users.username and users.image for *THAT* record (**which will correspond on users.id for notifications.senderID**) as well as for the main record(**notifications.recieverID**)

**IF POSSIBLE** I wanted to keep this in one query and outside of a PHP foreach loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the `users` table twice with differant alias names

```
SELECT notifications.senderID, notifications.receiverID, 
       receiver.username as receiver_name, receiver.image as receiver_image,
       sender.username as sender_name, sender.image as sender_image
FROM notifications
LEFT OUTER JOIN users as receiver ON receiver.id = notifications.receiverID
LEFT OUTER JOIN users as sender ON sender.id = notifications.senderID
WHERE notifications.receiverID = ' xxx '
```

Comment: I am getting the following error : **Unknown column 'users.image' in 'field list'**

Comment: you did not replace all occurances of `users` table in the `select` clause. It must be either sender or receiver instead

Answer (score 0):

This is the query for example

SELECT 
`User`.`id`, `User`.`username`, `User`.`password`, `User`.`email`, `User`.`role`, `User`.`created`, `User`.`modified`, `Userdetail`.`user_id`, `Userdetail`.`first_name`, `last name`, `Userdetail`.`address`, `Userdetail`.`telephone` 
FROM `cakephp_test`.`users` AS `User` 
LEFT JOIN `cakephp_test`.`userdetails` AS `Userdetail` 
ON (`Userdetail`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`)  WHERE `User`.`id` = 51 LIMIT 1

in your case

SELECT notifications.senderID, notifications.receiverID, users.username, users.image FROM database_name.users AS User LEFT JOIN database_name.notification AS notification ON (users.id = notifications.receiverID) WHERE User.id = 'xxx' LIMIT 1